How to remove <script> from HTML in angular dynamically
I am trying to integrate my application with third party payment. They provided the JS file which I am including in my HTML.
var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "URL"
    document.body.appendChild(script); 

I wanted to remove existing file and add same JS file again every time whenever user choose to perform some particular action.
How can I achieve this?

Just because a script element is removed, doesn't undo whatever running the code in it did. If the script was already executed and set up something, then simply re-adding the script might lead to some sort of incorrect behaviour.

Sounds more like you want to bind/unbind events for elements. Some libraries even provide convenient methods like .destroy() or similar to clear existing functionality

Because what you're trying to do is not really going to work, you would get more useful help if you explained exactly why you want to reload a script.

why you need to remove existing script and add it again. please explan more about your problem, your solution looks incorrect and I haven't seen such a pattern before.

Instead of adding and then removing the script - simply only add it when you need it.

I am integrating to third party payment , they provided the javascript which is responsible to show me the checkout page and few callback function though which we'll be knowing the status of the transaction . Now whenever I choose to do payment as mentioned above I am adding that script so that i can show the checkout page .... currently the problem is user try to pay multiple time every time js file is getting added in html which is creating issue

You will need to debug then if the script is really only added once, with console.log entries or step-by-step debugging (put results in the question!). If the payment is shown multiple times then the way you implemented it seems to be incorrect. Post the respective code in your angular project then, maybe that clarifies the issue.
